# Addressing Variable Multiplication in Constrained Infinity-Norm Maximization with Hypercube & Polyhedron Constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, global-optimization, reformulation-linearization

I am reaching out to this knowledgeable community for assistance with a complex optimization problem that I have been investigating. Here is the formulation of the problem I'm addressing:
$$\tag{1}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{cll}
      {\displaystyle \max_{\xi, \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{y} } }&  \left\|\mathbf{A}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\right\|_{\infty} \\
       \mbox{s.t.} & \mathbf{q}^{\intercal}\mathbf{y}\leq \left( \mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b} \right)^{\intercal} \mathbf{p}, & \\
       & \mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b}, &\\
       & \mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\leq \mathbf{q}, & \\
       & \xi\in\Xi,\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell}_{+}.&
   \end{array} \right.
$$
In this problem, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$, $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\mathbf{q} \in \mathbb{R}^{\ell}$ and $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times \ell}$. In addition, we assume that $\Xi$ is a hypercube $\Xi=\times_{i=1}^{d_{\xi}} [a_{i},b_{i}]$. This problem has unique characteristics that set it apart.

**Assumption:** Considering the optimization problem
$$\tag{2}
Q(\xi)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} {\displaystyle \min_{\mathbf{y}\geq 0}} & \mathbf{q}^{\intercal}\mathbf{y}  \\ \mbox{s.t.} & \mathbf{W} \mathbf{y}= \mathbf{A}\xi +\mathbf{b}. \end{array} \right.
$$
We assume that for all $\xi\in\Xi$, we have $Q(\xi)<\infty$. This condition ensures that strong duality holds for problem (2), and the solutions to the dual problem are at the vertices of the dual polyhedron $\{\mathbf{p}:\mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p} \leq \mathbf{q} \}$. This is crucial because the first constraint in problem (1) relates directly to the dual variables of problem (2).

**The drawback:** The main challenge with the problem (1) stems from the product of variables $\xi$ and $\mathbf{p}$ in the first constraint. It is worth noting that the maximization of an infinity norm is not an issue, as it can be recast as the maximization over a set of linear functions. Specifically, problem (1) can be reformulated as:
$$ \tag{3}
\max_{\mathbf{e}\in\mathcal{C}}\left\{ \begin{array}{cll}
      {\displaystyle \max_{\xi, \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{y} } }&  \mathbf{e}^{\intercal}\mathbf{A}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p} \\
       \mbox{s.t.} & \mathbf{q}^{\intercal}\mathbf{y}\leq \left( \mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b} \right)^{\intercal} \mathbf{p}, & \\
       & \mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b}, &\\
       & \mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\leq \mathbf{q}, & \\
       & \xi\in\Xi,\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell}_{+}.&
   \end{array} \right.
$$
where $\mathcal{C}:=\left\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\mathbf{e}_{2},\ldots,\mathbf{e}_{d},-\mathbf{e}_{1},-\mathbf{e}_{2},\ldots,-\mathbf{e}_{d} \right\}$ where  $\mathbf{e}_{i}$  is a canonical vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, i.e., the vector whose $i$-th component is $1$ and all other components are zero.

***I seek your guidance on approaches to tackle the problem (1), be it through innovative reformulations or through algorithms and numerical methods that can pave the way to a solution.***

Here are some insights that might influence your suggestions:

1. The nature of $\Xi$ as a hypercube seems advantageous. Empirical evidence suggests that optimal values of $\xi$ frequently reside on the hypercube's boundary. However, this is based on experimental findings and lacks theoretical validation.
2. The observation above might imply that problem (1) could be restricted to the vertices of the hypercube, potentially reducing it to a series of $2^d$ linear programs. Unfortunately, this is not universally applicable as I've encountered scenarios where the optimal $\xi$ values are not at the vertices.
3. I have attempted several reformulations:

   - ***Reformulation 1:*** The first reformulation of (1) is as follows:
     $$\left\{ \begin{array}{cll}
       {\displaystyle \max_{\xi, \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{y} } }&  \left\|\mathbf{A}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\right\|_{\infty} \\
        \mbox{s.t.} & \mathbf{q}^{\intercal}\mathbf{y}\leq  \mathbf{p}^{\intercal}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}, & \\
        & \mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b}, &\\
        & \mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\leq \mathbf{q}, & \\
        & \xi\in\Xi,\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell}_{+}.&
        \end{array} \right.$$
     This approach does not eliminate the variable multiplication issue.
   - ***Reformulation 2:*** Another reformulation of (1) is as follows:
     $$
     \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
       {\displaystyle \max_{\xi\in\Xi, \mathbf{p} } }&  \left\|\mathbf{A}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\right\|_{\infty} \\
        \mbox{s.t.} & {\displaystyle\sup_{\tilde{\mathbf{p}}\: :\: \mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\tilde{\mathbf{p}}\leq \mathbf{q} }}\left( \mathbf{A}\xi +\mathbf{b} \right)^{\intercal} \tilde{\mathbf{p}}\leq \left( \mathbf{A}\xi +\mathbf{b} \right)^{\intercal} \mathbf{p}, \\
        & \mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\leq \mathbf{q}.
        \end{array} \right.
     $$
     This might hint at addressing the problem with semi-infinite programming techniques, such as the decomposition method outlined at [see this [link]](https://neos-guide.org/guide/algorithms/discretization/). Yet, this approach is problematic due to the persistent variable multiplication and the challenges in initializing the method. Specifically, the master program and the Oracle program will continue to have multiplication of variables. In addition, another inconvenience lies in starting the method, this is because this type of method begins in its first iteration with a master program that removes the semi-infinite constraint, that is a drawback because if the dual polyhedron is unbounded, then that master program gives infinity and the algorithm will not be able to start.
   - ***Reformulation 3:*** The Assumption introduced earlier in this discourse proves pivotal at this juncture. It facilitates the recasting of problem (1) into the following form:
     $$\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
       {\displaystyle \max_{\xi\in\Xi, \mathbf{p}\in\{\pi_{1},\ldots,\pi_{M}\} } }&  \left\|\mathbf{A}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p}\right\|_{\overline{q}} \\
        \mbox{s.t.} & \left( \mathbf{A}\xi +\mathbf{b} \right)^{\intercal} \pi_{i}\leq \left( \mathbf{A}\xi +\mathbf{b} \right)^{\intercal} \mathbf{p} \qquad \forall i\in[M]  
        \end{array} \right.$$
     where $\pi_{1},\pi_{2},\dots,\pi_{M}$ represent the extreme points of the dual polyhedron $\{\mathbf{p}:\mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\mathbf{p} \leq \mathbf{q} \}$. The practicality of this reformulation, however, remains elusive to me. Ideally, I would prefer to devise a method that circumvents the necessity of computing the extreme points of the dual polyhedron.
   - ***Reformulation 4:*** The last reformulation I obtained is the following:
     $$
     \max_{\mathbf{e}\in\mathcal{C}}\max_{\xi\in\Xi}\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
     {\displaystyle \min_{\gamma,\varphi,\phi} } & \mathbf{q}^{\intercal}\gamma + (\mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b})^{\intercal}\phi \\
     \mathrm{s.t}& \mathbf{W}\gamma-(\mathbf{A}\xi+\mathbf{b})\varphi=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{e}\\
     & \mathbf{q}\varphi+\mathbf{W}^{\intercal}\phi\geq \mathbf{0}\\
     & \gamma\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell}_{+},\varphi\in\mathbb{R},\phi\in\mathbb{R}^{m}.    
     \end{array}\right.
     $$
     It leverages a duality argument based on reformulation (3), though its practicality is uncertain.

Comment: The product of variables constraint is non-convex, and I don't think there will be a free lunch in solving it. What problem dimensions do you need to solve this for, and do you have a solution time requirement (such as real-time)?